# How can I add alternate subject names when creating a CSR using xca?

Tags: certificate, x509

openSUSE and SLES dropped their old CA management, now recommending to use [xca](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/).

While it was easy to add *alternate subject names* like hostname aliases or IP addresses in the old CA management, I could not find a way how to do it in `xca`.

So I wonder: Is is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: On migration: I think it could have been answered at Super User, too (and it would be "on-topic", right?).

Answer (score 0):

https://hohnstaedt.de/xca-doc/html/certificate-input.html#wizard
points you to https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html

which gives some examples of the config for specifying SAN values

```
subjectAltName = email:copy, email:my@example.com, URI:http://my.example.com/

subjectAltName = IP:192.168.7.1

subjectAltName = IP:13::17

subjectAltName = email:my@example.com, RID:1.2.3.4

subjectAltName = otherName:1.2.3.4;UTF8:some other identifier

[extensions]
subjectAltName = dirName:dir_sect

[dir_sect]
C = UK
O = My Organization
OU = My Unit
CN = My Name
```

Comment: Well, I have a script working with openssl commands directly. The old YaST CA management would easily allow adding host aliases and lists of IP addresses (among others). `xca`seems to have a nice user interface, but how to add alternate names looks quite like a mystery to me. "*The subject-alternative-name extension must be used to define additional DNS names, even wildcards*" is quite vague.